# Named stage returns: Error parsing reference: "golang:1.7.3 as builder" is not a valid repository/tag

Tags: docker

On Gentoo Linux kernel 4.12.12

added docker info and version below

docker info : https://pastebin.com/Ph9ibMna

```
> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.27 (downgraded from 1.30)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   cec0b72
 Built:        Thu Sep 28 07:14:33 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.2-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   f5ec1e2
 Built:        Wed Sep 13 23:43:20 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

command:

```
> docker build -t some-test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  234.9MB
Step 1/1 : FROM golang:1.7.3 as builder
Error parsing reference: "golang:1.7.3 as builder" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

from Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.7.3 as builder
```

example taken from [name-your-build-stages](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/#name-your-build-stages)

Comment: Add complete output of `docker version` and `docker info`

Comment: thanks @TarunLalwani, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your client is `17.06.2-ce` and server is `17.03.2-ce`. Multi stage build came in `17.06` i believe, so you need that version on the server. It is the server that processes the build. The client will only send the information to the server

So upgrade your server and it will work fine

Comment: I upgraded docker but forgot to restart the service, thanks again for your help ;)